# jQuery $.post not returning value

Tags: jquery, .post

I know this have been asked a lot, I searched and tested a few answers on the forum.
But this can't seem to work, but looks rather easy to solve. I'm trying to post a simple contact form, and after validating/sending, return a fail/success value.

But this response variable is not working!
Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contact-send').click(function() {
        $.post("http://talaguim.com/contato-send.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {
            if (response == "ok") {
                mensagem = "Sua mensagem foi enviada.";
                type(mensagem);
            } else {
                mensagem = "Ops, o e-mail é inválido, verifique de novo.";
                type(mensagem); 
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
 });
```

My HTML is:

```
    <form action="" method="POST" id="mycontactform">
        <div id="contact-form">
            <textarea id="contact-text" name="message"></textarea>
            <div class="contact-linhabaixo">
                <input type="text" class="contact-input" name="name" id="name" value="Nome"><input type="text" class="contact-input" name="email" id="email" value="E-mail"><input type="submit" class="contact-btn" id="contact-send" value="Enviar">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: When I the url it returns `nein`.  Is that due to some conditional logic?

Comment: It returns nein because the field validation is checking for an email field and not finding anything. 'Nein' means no in german :).

When the email field is correct, returns 'ok'.

Answer (score 0):

can you add an `alert()` or `console.log` and see what is being returned in the response? It could be an object and not a string, or it could have white space, you can try `.trim()` as well.

You can also try added an error function to your call:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#contact-send').click(function() {
            $.post("http://talaguim.com/contato-send.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {
                if (response == "ok") {
                    mensagem = "Sua mensagem foi enviada.";
                    type(mensagem);
                } else {
                    mensagem = "Ops, o e-mail é inválido, verifique de novo.";
                    type(mensagem); 
                }
            }).fail(function(msg) {
              alert(msg.status + " " + msg.statusText);
            });
        return false;
    });
 });
```

Comment: Not exactly an answer is it? Belongs in the comments imo.

Comment: I've tried a alert before and it simply doesn't appear nothing.
But with this code you provided, a alert with "0 error" appears.
What could it be?

Comment: You may need to post your php to check that it is syntactically correct, or check that the data you are posting is what the php expects. You also might be running into same-origin policy, or that the site that has the php is not up.

Comment: Ok, I think I found it after this '0 error'. I was trying to test it in localhost but ajaxing the php script that was online.

The error means the server was unreachable or invalid. So I tested everything locally and it worked.